# AngularJS operations with directive attributes

Tags: angularjs

Small question. I can't find any solution

I have some directives that I need to insert into my tags in some cases.

My form object

```
function AppCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.form ={
        name:{
            type: 'text',
            validate: 'letters'
        },
        tel:{
            type: 'number',
            validate: 'digits'
        }
    }
}
```

My directive

```
<body ng-app ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<input type="{{v.type}}" placeholder="{{k}}" {{v.type=='number' ? 'string-to-number' : '' }} {{v.validate}} value=""  ng-repeat="(k,v) in form">
</body>
```

I need to render 'validate' and 'string-to-number' atributes in inputs. But my code doesn't fire

Here is jsfiddle example
http://jsfiddle.net/FxM3B/517/

Answer (score 1):

I updated the [plunker with a possible solution](http://jsfiddle.net/FxM3B/518/)

```
   <div ng-repeat="(k,v) in form">

<input ng-if="v.type ==='number'" type="{{v.type}}" placeholder="{{k}}"  validate="{{v.validate}}" value="" string-to-number>
    <input ng-if="v.type !=='number'" type="{{v.type}}" placeholder="{{k}}"  validate="{{v.validate}}" value="">
    </div>
```

Check with ng-if the value and add markup for the two options.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add an HTML attribute this way, you should take a look at ng-attr, but you might need to change your directive because it adds the attribute in all case, only the content is dynamic.

Otherwise this article explain several solutions : http://www.thinkingmedia.ca/2015/03/conditionally-add-a-html-element-attribute-value-in-angularjs/

Answer (score 0):

Since the names of attributes  you want to add to an element are the values of properties of your model, you can't use ng-attr directive.
You can author you own directive that handles such situations.
Here's        [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/rustam/FxM3B/519/)

```
.directive('boolAttrs', function(){
    return function(scope, element, attrs){

        var propExpr = attrs['boolAttrs'];

        if (propExpr)
        {
            var data = angular.fromJson(propExpr);

            if (angular.isArray(data) && data.length > 0) {

                angular.forEach(data, function (value, index, array) {

                    var propValue = scope.$eval(value);

                    if (angular.isFunction(propValue))
                        propValue = propValue();

                    if (propValue)
                        element.attr(propValue, "");
                });
            }
        }
    };
})
```

You can apply this directive this way:

```
 bool-attrs='["v.validate", "v.type == \"number\" ? \"string-to-number\" : \"\" "]'
```

A value for bool-attrs should be a valid json array string, that defines expressions to evaluete to determine the names of attributes to be inserted.